# Can I Substitute this document.getElementById("Id") to getBy("Id") a custom function that returns the same?

Tags: javascript, html, web, dom-manipulation

I mean this:

```js
document.getElementById('Id')
```

With This:

```js
function getById(ID){
return document.getElementById('Id')
}
getById('Id')
```

I am developing a project it requires using thousands of these...
I'm using this with other DOM manipulation methods . Does it have any consequences?

Comment: No, that should not normally have any negative consequences. And you can do `var getById = document.getElementById;`, and achieve the same thing already.

Comment: @CBroe That should be `const getById = document.getElementById.bind(document);`. See [JavaScript function aliasing doesn't seem to work](/q/1007340/4642212).

Comment: Hi Javid ! beware to `return document.getElementById(ID);` ;)

Comment: Consider _why_ “it requires using thousands of these”. Why do you need thousands of IDs? Are you using other means of DOM traversal like prototype methods of [`Element`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element#methods) and [`Node`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Node#methods), [`querySelectorAll`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), [event delegation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation), [iteration](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#instance_methods), etc.?

Comment: why not just use `document.querySelector('#Id')`? which is an all-in-one selector. [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)